# Sending gifs inside a Embed in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=["rule34"])
async def nsfw(ctx):
        if not ctx.channel.is_nsfw():
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=":x: Channel Is Not NSFW",
                color=discord.Colour.purple()
            )
            embed.set_image(url="https://giphy.com/gifs/W5C9c8nqoaDJWh34i6")
        else:
            async with ctx.channel.typing():
                memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit("rule34").hot()
                post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
                for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
                    submission = memes_submissions.__next__()
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=submission.title,
                     color=discord.Colour.purple()
                )
                embed.set_image(url=submission.url)
                embed.add_field(name="Author", value="u/" + submission.author.name, )
                embed.add_field(name="View Online", value=f"[Link]({submission.url})", )
                embed.add_field(name="Subreddit", value="r/rule34", )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my code. In `if not ctx.channel.is_nsfw():` part i want to send a gif. I know that by default you can't send a gif I am pretty sure there is a way for it. If there is I don't know and would be happy to learn from you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting an image in an embed, it needs to be the direct link to the image (https://example.com/path/to/image.png) - you'll know this if your url ends in a filetype (`.png`, `.bmp`, `.jpg`, `.gif` etc.).

To get this, you want to right click your image/gif, and `Copy Image Location`:

[image]

So in your case, you'd want:

```py
embed.set_image(url="https://media0.giphy.com/media/W5C9c8nqoaDJWh34i6/giphy.gif")
```

---

**Reference:**

- [`Embed.set_image()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image)